# Does the founder org of a hyperledger fabric private network have all the orderers?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

If BigBank#1 starts a Hyperledger Fabric private network with a couple of peers, an orderer and fabric CA and down the line offers a service to BigBank#2 and invites it to access its network, does that mean that only the founder (i.e. BigBank#1) can have an orderer on its network?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No:

- SmallBank can also create an orderer of its own and have the peers of BigBank join it.
- If BigBank uses a Kafka orderer, it can have SmallBank use its own Ordering service nodes to connect to BigBank's existing Kafka service, or they can grow the kafka cluster and connect between the kafka nodes.

Comment: How do you add new orderers to the existing ordering service? Are there any references on how to do that? TIA!